# iOS in app purchase - query regarding screenshot for review

Tags: ios5, in-app-purchase

I tried googling but have not got any definitive answer :
Is a screen shot mandatory for an in-app purchase ?

My app is already live on the app store - so is the screenshot really pertaining to the application screenshot ?

My in-app purchase is really a non consumable - which will be like adding more points / coins like in a game

so really there is no screenshot in my case which makes sense

any thoughts please ?
Thanks
akila

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **Question 1** - Is a screen shot mandatory for an in-app purchase ?
  **Answer** - Yes, for submit any in-app purchase for review, it is required. Without screen shot it will not approved.
- **Question 2** - My app is already live on the app store - so is the screenshot really pertaining to the application screenshot ?
  **Answer** - You need to provide screen shot in such a way so reviewer can see where you have used your in-app purchase in application.
- **Question 3** - My in-app purchase is really a non consumable - which will be like adding more points / coins like in a game

  so really there is no screenshot in my case which makes sense
  **Answer** - Though any type of in-app purchase you have used but you need to provide screen shot in itunes connect. If you have not provided screen shot than you will not able to select that in-app at the time of ***"Ready To Upload Binary"*** and it will not get approved from apple.

For more refence you can follow apple's [In-App Purchase document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/Introduction.html)

They mentioned,

> **Uploading Screenshots**
>
> **Before you submit your In-App Purchase, you *must* upload a screenshot of your In-App Purchase for review purposes only.** This screenshot will not be displayed on the App Store or user device. Screenshots must be at least 640 x 920 pixels and at least 72 dpi.

Comment: The Apple's link above is dead. Here is the new one: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/Introduction.html